# Magento 2.3 admin "This page isn’t working, mysite.local redirected you too many times"

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I got an error after installing the extension pack using composer (Magento blogs), everything is perfect but after running, my website is like this :

[admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CmMu.png)
[fontend page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CmMu.png)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please help us help you. What have you tried?

Comment: I used the same as the manufacturer instructions. i used : # composer require magefan/module-blog;  # php bin/magento setup:upgrade;  #php bin/magento setup:di:compile;  # php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;     tóm tắt phần mềm của tôi: window 10, php 7.2.0, magento 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to check permissions for this module files.

Other solution: try to disable Magefan_Blog with `php bin/magento module:disable Magefan_Blog` if the site will come back the problem in that module and you will know where the issue.